# Posting a string array as one parameter in node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am very new to node.js and REST in general. My model has following schema:

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "student name"
    },
    "family": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "family name"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "list of subjects taken",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": { "type": "string" },
      "uniqueItems": true
}
```

First two properties are straight forward as they are string. But I am confused how to post an array for `subjects`. I have coded the model like this:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var StudentSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    family: String,
    subject: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

I don't know whether I have made it correct or not. When I tried to POST using POSTMAN, it persisted the record, but I don't know whether it was stored as an array or String only. How do I verify that? How do I add a validation that length of the array has to be >1 for persisting?

Comment: use the shell or a tool such as robomongo to find the data in your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the validation part

```
var StudentSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    family: String,
    subject: {
              type: [String],
              validate: [arrayLengthGreaterOne, '{PATH} size has to be > 1']
             }
});

function arrayLengthGreaterOne(val) {
  return val.length > 1;
}
```

What do you mean by "don't know how it was stored?"

I would just look up the date via `db.find()` in mongo itself but your syntax looks fine so I guess it got stored correctly.

Comment: How do I access this "{PATH} size has to be > 1" message? I want to different error message for different errors